# How to model class hierarchies in Haskell?

Tags: oop, functional-programming, haskell

I am a C# developer. Coming from OO side of the world, I start with thinking in terms of interfaces, classes and type hierarchies. Because of lack of OO in Haskell, sometimes I find myself stuck and I cannot think of a way to model certain problems with Haskell.

How to model, in Haskell, real world situations involving class hierarchies such as the one shown here: http://www.braindelay.com/danielbray/endangered-object-oriented-programming/isHierarchy-4.gif

Comment: It depends largely on what operations you want to perform on them. Can you describe how you'd want to use objects of those classes in your program?

Comment: I have picked a random example. Feel free to assume any operations. I just want to get the general idea about how such situations are handled in Haskell.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Let's assume the following operations: Humans can speak, Dogs can bark, and all members of a species can mate with members of the same species if they have opposite gender. I would define this in haskell like this:

```
data Gender = Male | Female deriving Eq

class Species s where
    gender :: s -> Gender

-- Returns true if s1 and s2 can conceive offspring
matable :: Species a => a -> a -> Bool
matable s1 s2 = gender s1 /= gender s2

data Human = Man | Woman
data Canine = Dog | Bitch

instance Species Human where
    gender Man = Male
    gender Woman = Female

instance Species Canine where
    gender Dog = Male
    gender Bitch = Female

bark Dog = "woof"
bark Bitch = "wow"

speak Man s = "The man says " ++ s
speak Woman s = "The woman says " ++ s
```

Now the operation `matable` has type `Species s => s -> s -> Bool`, `bark` has type `Canine -> String` and `speak` has type `Human -> String -> String`.

I don't know whether this helps, but given the rather abstract nature of the question, that's the best I could come up with.

Edit: In response to Daniel's comment:

A simple hierarchy for collections could look like this (ignoring already existing classes like Foldable and Functor):

```
class Foldable f where
    fold :: (a -> b -> a) -> a -> f b -> a

class Foldable m => Collection m where
    cmap :: (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
    cfilter :: (a -> Bool) -> m a -> m a

class Indexable i where
    atIndex :: i a -> Int -> a

instance Foldable [] where
    fold = foldl

instance Collection [] where
    cmap = map
    cfilter = filter

instance Indexable [] where
    atIndex = (!!)

sumOfEvenElements :: (Integral a, Collection c) => c a -> a
sumOfEvenElements c = fold (+) 0 (cfilter even c)
```

Now sumOfEvenElements takes any kind of collection of integrals and returns the sum of all even elements of that collection.

Comment: What if class hierarchy is more than one level deep? ADTs won't apply in such case, will they?

Comment: I think that the question is more of how a class hierarchy using inheritance would look like in Haskell. For instance, what would Iterable <- Collection <- List <- ArrayList would look like?

Comment: Yes that's what I mean. Thanks Daniel for clarifying my question.

Comment: I think a class hierarchy that is deeper than one level has to use kinds, or type of types (like the Omega language). Or you can simulate using dependent types.

Comment: What would the type of a variable which can hold a human or a canine be?

Comment: Actually, a better question is: how would I store a list of mixed humans and canines?

Comment: ...incidentally, as an aside, in your model canines and humans can interbreed.

Comment: @DavidGiven You'd need to create a wrapper type that can either be human or canine. That'd be either `data Being = Canine Canine | Human Human` if you want to be able to distinguish whether the thing you get out of your list is a canine or human or the existential type `data Being = forall s. Species s => Being s` if you want to be able to put in any type of Species and you don't need to downcast later. Regarding your aside: Good catch. Fixed.

Answer (score 32):

First of all: Standard OO design is not going to work nicely in Haskell. You can fight the language and try to make something similar, but it will be an exercise in frustration. So step one is **look for Haskell-style solutions to your problem instead of looking for ways to write an OOP-style solution in Haskell**.

But that's easier said than done! Where to even start?

So, let's disassemble the gritty details of what OOP does for us, and think about how those might look in Haskell.

- **Objects**: Roughly speaking, an object is the combination of some data with methods operating on that data. In Haskell, data is normally structured using *algebraic data types*; methods can be thought of as *functions taking the object's data as an initial, implicit argument*.
- **Encapsulation**: However, the ability to inspect an object's data is usually limited to its own methods. In Haskell, there are various ways to hide a piece of data, two examples are:

  - *Define the data type in a separate module that doesn't export the type's constructors*. Only functions in that module can inspect or create values of that type. This is somewhat comparable to `protected` or `internal` members.
  - *Use partial application*. Consider the function `map` with its arguments flipped. If you apply it to a list of `Int`s, you'll get a function of type `(Int -> b) -> [b]`. The list you gave it is still "there", in a sense, but nothing else can use it except through the function. This is comparable to `private` members, and the original function that's being partially applied is comparable to an OOP-style constructor.
- **"Ad-hoc" polymorphism**: Often, in OO programming we only care that something implements a method; when we call it, the specific method called is determined based on the actual type. Haskell provides *type classes* for compile-time function overloading, which are in many ways *more* flexible than what's found in OOP languages.
- **Code reuse**: Honestly, my opinion is that code reuse via inheritance was and is a mistake. Mix-ins as found in something like Ruby strike me as a better OO solution. At any rate, in any functional language, the standard approach is to factor out common behavior using higher-order functions, then specialize the general-purpose form. A classic example here are `fold` functions, which generalize almost all iterative loops, list transformations, and linearly recursive functions.
- **Interfaces**: Depending on how you're using an interface, there are different options:

  - *To decouple implementation*: Polymorphic functions with type class constraints are what you want here. For example, the function `sort` has type `(Ord a) => [a] -> [a]`; it's completely decoupled from the details of the type you give it other than it must be a list of some type implementing `Ord`.
  - *Working with multiple types with a shared interface*: For this you need either a language extension for *existential types*, or to keep it simple, use some variation on *partial application* as above--instead of values and functions you can apply to them, apply the functions ahead of time and work with the results.
- **Subtyping**, a.k.a. the "is-a" relationship: This is where you're mostly out of luck. But--speaking from experience, having been a professional C# developer for years--cases where you really *need* subtyping aren't terribly common. Instead, think about the above, and what behavior you're trying to capture with the subtyping relationship.

You might also find [this blog post](http://blog.ezyang.com/2010/05/design-patterns-in-haskel/) helpful; it gives a quick summary of what you'd use in Haskell to solve the same problems that some standard Design Patterns are often used for in OOP.

As a final addendum, as a C# programmer, you might find it interesting to research the connections between it and Haskell. Quite a few people responsible for C# are also Haskell programmers, and some recent additions to C# were heavily influenced by Haskell. Most notable is probably the monadic structure underlying LINQ, with IEnumerable being essentially the list monad.

Comment: Wow, now that's an in-depth analysis. We have the same opinion about inheritance, combining interface and behavior is a terrible choice imho...

Comment: Great answer! I think that type classes are *parametric* polymorphism, btw.

Comment: @Jonathan Sterling: Actually, no: Parametric polymorphism means abstracting over opaque types without any knowledge of what they are--the corresponding guarantee is that the function will behave identically for all type parameters. This is just regular type variables in Haskell, or "generics" in various languages. Ad-hoc polymorphism means choosing different behavior for different types, which uses type classes in Haskell or overloaded functions in various other languages.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @camccann! I have a lot to learn.

Comment: @Jonathan Sterling: The terms are often used ambiguously or misleadingly, particularly when arcane-but-precise academic jargon starts getting mixed with descriptive-but-fuzzy industry jargon, so it's easy to get the wrong idea. The same thing happens with formal mathematical concepts vs. their hand-wavy use in Haskell, which has led to me embarrassing myself in front of a couple mathematicians!

Answer (score 7):

Instead of classes and objects, Haskell uses *abstract data types*.  These are really two compatible views on the problem of organizing ways of *constructing* and *observing* information.  The best help I know of on this subject is William Cook's essay [Object-Oriented Programming Versus Abstract Data Types](http://userweb.cs.utexas.edu/~wcook/papers/OOPvsADT/CookOOPvsADT90.pdf).  He has some very clear explanations to the effect that

- In a class-based system, code is organized around different ways of *constructing* abstractions.  Generally each different way of constructing an abstraction is assigned its own class.  The methods know how to observe properties of that construction only.
- In an ADT-based system (like Haskell), code is organized around different ways of *observing* abstractions.  Generally each different way of observing an abstraction is assigned its own function.  The function knows *all* the ways the abstraction could be constructed, and it knows how to observe a single property, but of any construction.

Cook's paper will show you a nice matrix layout of abstractions and teach you how to organize any class as an ADY or vice versa.

Class *hierarchies* involve one more element: the reuse of implementations through inheritance.  In Haskell, such reuse is achieved through first-class functions instead: a function in a `Primate` abstraction is a value and an implementation of the `Human` abstraction can reuse any functions of the `Primate` abstraction, can wrap them to modify their results, and so on.

**There is not an exact fit** between design with class hierarchies and design with abstract  data types.  If you try to transliterate from one to the other, you will wind up with something awkward and not idiomatic—kind of like a FORTRAN program written in Java.
But if you understand the principles of class hierarchies and the principles of abstract data types, you can take a solution to a problem in one style and craft a reasonably idiomatic solution to the same problem in the other style.  It does take practice.

---

Addendum: It's also possible to use Haskell's type-class system to try to emulate class hierarchies, but that's a different kettle of fish.  Type classes are similar enough to ordinary classes that a number of standard examples work, but they are different enough that there can also be some very big surprises and misfits.  While type classes are an invaluable tool for a Haskell programmer, I would recommend that anyone learning Haskell learn to design programs using abstract data types.

Comment: I don't understand how first class functions can be used as substitute for inheritance. Can you please give an example?

Answer (score 2):

Haskell is my favorite language, is a pure functional language. 
It does not have side effects, there is no assignment.
If you find to hard the transition to this language, maybe F# is a better place to start with functional programming. F# is not pure.

Objects encapsulate states, there is a way to achieve this in Haskell, but this is one of the issues that takes more time to learn because you must learn some category theory concepts to deeply understand monads. There is syntactic sugar that lets you see monads like non destructive assignment, but in my opinion it is better to spend more time understanding the basis of category theory (the notion of category) to get a better understanding.

Before trying to program in OO style in Haskell, you should ask yourself if you really use the object oriented style in C#, many programmers use OO languages, but their programs are written in the structured style.

The data declaration allows you to define data structures combining products (equivalent to structure in C language) and unions (equivalent to union in C), the deriving part o the declaration allows to inherit default methods.

A data type (data structure) belongs to a class if has an implementation of the set of methods in the class.
For example, if you can define a show :: a -> String method for your data type, then it belong to the class Show, you can define your data type as an instance of the Show class.

This is different of the use of class in some OO languages where it is used as a way to define structures + methods.

A data type is abstract if it is independent of it's implementation. You create, mutate, and destroy the object by an abstract interface, you do not need to know how it is implemented.

Abstraction is supported in Haskell, it is very easy to declare. 
For example this code from the Haskell site:

```
data Tree a = Nil 
            | Node { left  :: Tree a,
                     value :: a,
                     right :: Tree a }
```

declares the selectors left, value, right.
the constructors may be defined as follows if you want to add them to the export list in the module declaration:

```
node = Node 
nil = Nil
```

Modules are build in a similar way as in Modula. Here is another example from the same site:

```
module Stack (Stack, empty, isEmpty, push, top, pop) where

empty :: Stack a
isEmpty :: Stack a -> Bool
push :: a -> Stack a -> Stack a
top :: Stack a -> a
pop :: Stack a -> (a,Stack a)

newtype Stack a = StackImpl [a] -- opaque!
empty = StackImpl []
isEmpty (StackImpl s) = null s
push x (StackImpl s) = StackImpl (x:s)
top (StackImpl s) = head s
pop (StackImpl (s:ss)) = (s,StackImpl ss)
```

There is more to say about this subject, I hope this comment helps!